# Unable to interact with website elements after authenticate in chrome

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Unable to interact with elements when I fill authentication popup details using selenium in chrome.

I have one website where it asks for auth. login as soon as we hit main URL. It works fine when I enter auth manually in normal chrome browser or even manually in incognito window.

When I run via selenium it works fine in Firefox but not in chrome, In chrome it throws below error in console when run via selenium :

[image]

**My Code :**

```
  HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
            cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
            chromePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + prop.getProperty("chromeDriverPath");
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromePath);
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
 driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

            driver.get("https://username:password@website.com/login")
```

**Versions I use :**

```
3.14 for all selenium related dependencies 
ChromeDriver 2.44
Chrome 70.0
```

Steps like what is happening :

1. It comes to login page of website and auth already passed as I included in URL
2. It login with my user and password from login web page of website
3. Now it stuck. Can not click on any element and no other action can be performed. And fired error which I attached as screenshot.